# How to save any kind of file in windows phone 7 isolated storage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is there any techniques or you can share some code snippets on how to save any kind of file that is supported by wp7?

Answer (score 3):

You can write and read basically everything from/into the isolated storage. You can create folders and files etc. Think of it as a whole filesystem just for your app.

You can write text files like:

```
using (var myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using (var fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("filename", FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
{
    writer.Write("Hi I'm a string!");
}
```

or binary data like:

```
using (var myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using (var fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("filename", FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage))
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
{
    // write some bytes
    writer.Write(new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3}, 0, 4);
}
```

See [this](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files) tutorial for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

The following links will help you understand clearly about IsolatedStorage in windows phone 7, with example code blocks and usage

[IsolagedStorageFile Msdn documentation with example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx)

[Working with IsolatedStorage Files](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/Isolated_Storage#files)